# how to link text to another page

Tags: html

I am having some issues with linking the word "solo player" to another page I have already written the code for it but it wont work

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<h2>Fade in Overlay</h2>
<p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>
<div class="container">
  <img src="Image%20Character%202.PNG" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:500px;height:500px; text-align:center">
  <a href="soloplayer.html"></a>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Solo Player</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: The text "Solo Player" is not in the `<a>` tag .

Comment: i have managed to get it fixed but thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Place the text inside anchor tag:

```
<a href="soloplayer.html">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Solo Player</div>
  </div>
</a>
```

You will probably need to make the anchor tag with `display: block` style and reset the default styling.

Comment: i have written what you have written onto my code and it worked thank you so much Rado for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The text is outside the a tag. So you can put `<div class="overlay">...</div>` inside the a tag.

```
<a href="soloplayer.html">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Solo Player</div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: i have managed to get it fixed but thank you so much mswgen for your help :)